# MS SQL Query para JSP

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, jsp, data

Estou criando um website baseado na linguagem JSP porém não sei como retornar uma **consulta** ao qual realizei no **MSSQL Server**, o mesmo segue abaixo:

```
DECLARE @Nomes VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Nomes = COALESCE(@Nomes + ', ', '') + nome
FROM usuarios
WHERE nome IS NOT NULL
PRINT @Nomes
```

> **Resultado**: nome1,nome2,nome3

Estou com o seguinte código na página JSP, pretendo que ele retorne o mesmo valor da consulta realizada no **MSSQL Server** em uma **String**

```
<%
Connection currentCon = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    String sql = "DECLARE @Nomes VARCHAR(8000) SELECT @Nomes = COALESCE(@Nomes + ', ', '') + nome FROM usuarios WHERE nome IS NOT NULL";
    st = currentCon.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    String resultado = null;

    while(rs.next()) {
        resultado = rs.getString(1);
    }

    System.out.println(test);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Falha ao acessar o banco de dados: " + e);
}
%>
```